# I can't find a class API DOC reference for tensorflow

Tags: api, tensorflow, reference

I am struggling to find the API for a particular class in tensorflow.
For example, I am interested in finding the specs for this class:

tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor

Sorry if this sounds as a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow is not that well documented yet. The docs are generated from the comments (the project is hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/)) and in your case, there are none.

For insights like that, you will have to read the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py).